# Redis Gears events in cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redisgears

I have a redis cluster with the following configuration :

```
91d426e9a569b1c1ad84d75580607e3f99658d30 127.0.0.1:7002@17002 myself,master - 0 1596197488000 1 connected 0-5460
9ff311ae9f413b48578ff0519e97fef2ced57b1e 127.0.0.1:7003@17003 master - 0 1596197490000 2 connected 5461-10922
4de4d36b968bd0b5b5dc8023cb00a5a2ab62effc 127.0.0.1:7004@17004 master - 0 1596197492253 3 connected 10923-16383
a32088043c31c5d3f20828bfe06306b9f0717635 127.0.0.1:7005@17005 slave 91d426e9a569b1c1ad84d75580607e3f99658d30 0 1596197490251 1 connected
b5e9ec7851dfd8dc5ab0cf35c230a0e716dd934c 127.0.0.1:7006@17006 slave 9ff311ae9f413b48578ff0519e97fef2ced57b1e 0 1596197489000 2 connected
a34cc74321e1c75e4cf203248bc0883833c928c7 127.0.0.1:7007@17007 slave 4de4d36b968bd0b5b5dc8023cb00a5a2ab62effc 0 1596197492000 3 connected
```

I want to create a set with all keys in the cluster by listening key operations with redis gears and store key names in a redis set called `keys`.

To do thant, I run this redis gears command

```
RG.PYEXECUTE "GearsBuilder('KeysReader').foreach(lambda x: execute('sadd', 'keys', x['key'])).register(readValue=False)"
```

It work, but only if the updated key is store on the same node of the key `keys`

Example :

With my cluster configuration, the key `keys` is store un node `91d426e9a569b1c1ad84d75580607e3f99658d30` (the first node).

If i run :

```
SET foo bar
SET bar foo
SMEMBERS keys
```

I have the following result :

```
127.0.0.1:7002> SET foo bar
-> Redirected to slot [12182] located at 127.0.0.1:7004
OK
127.0.0.1:7004> SET bar foo
-> Redirected to slot [5061] located at 127.0.0.1:7002
OK
127.0.0.1:7002> SMEMBERS keys
1) "bar"
2) "keys"
127.0.0.1:7002>
```

The first key name `foo` is not saved in the set `keys`.

Is it possible to have key names on other nodes saved in the `keys` set with redis gears ?

Redis version : 6.0.6

Redis gears version : 1.0.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key was written to a shard that does not contain the 'keys' key you need to make sure to move it to another shard with the repartition operation (https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/operations.html#repartition), so this should work:

```
RG.PYEXECUTE "GearsBuilder('KeysReader').repartition(lambda x: 'keys').foreach(lambda x: execute('sadd', 'keys', x['key'])).register(readValue=False)"
```

The repartition operation will move the record to the correct shard and the 'sadd' will succeed.

Another option is to maintain a set per shard and collect them using another Gear function. To do that you need to use the hashtag function (https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/runtime.html#hashtag) to make sure the set created belongs to the current shard. So the following registration will maintain a set per shard:

```
RG.PYEXECUTE "GearsBuilder('KeysReader').foreach(lambda x: execute('sadd', 'keys{%s}' % hashtag(), x['key'])).register(mode='sync', readValue=False)"
```

Notice that the sync mode tells RedisGears not to start a distributed execution and it should be much faster to follow the keys this way.

Then to collect all the values:

```
RG.PYEXECUTE "GB('ShardsIDReader').flatmap(lambda x: execute('smembers', 'keys{%s}' % hashtag())).run()"
```

The first approach is good for read-intensive use cases and the second approach is good for write-intensive use cases. Depends on your use case you need to chose the right approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Complementary information : with a self make cluster you need to run the RG.REFRESHCLUSTER command. Otherwise the registration with RG.PYEXECUTE is not propagated to other nodes.